# MSSQLLOCALDB databases aren't listed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, localdb

I used the ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates in Visual Studio 2015 to create an ASP.NET 5 site. According to the config.json file, there's a database in (localdb)\mssqllocaldb.

I want to move that database to my actual SQL Server, but when I connect to the (localdb)\mssqllocaldb server in SQL Server Management Studio to start the backup process, there are no databases listed. Where is it?

Any idea on how I can migrate that database if I can't find it in SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Connect to Server" login, there is an "Options" button. That opens a "Connection Properties" tab that lets you find specify a database, either by manually entering the name or browsing for it. When connecting that way, it *does* appear in the list.

Comment: Just add the complete connection string - worked for me:  (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb

Comment: In visual Studio 2019/2022, in 'Server Explorer' toolbar at the top, click on 'SQL Server Object Explorer' icon. The databases will then show up under 'Sql Server' tree. If your database is not listed in VS 2019, try with VS 2022.

Answer (score 29):

I had this problem also and just got it working (I'm doing the MVC-Movie MVC6 Tutorial - i'm just at the 'Adding a Model' section where you create a connection to a Local Database : [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html)).

Visual Studio 2015/SQL Server 2014 uses a different path than 2012/2013. I previously had VS2012 and VS2013 installed and had created local databases in each. VS2012 created a connection as: (localdb)\v11.0 and SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) as (localdb)\ProjectsV12.

To get the (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB working you:

1. Open CMD Prompt and type `SQLLocalDB.exe info`
   this shows all the current database servers on your local connection
2. You should see an option here for MSSQLLocalDB. 
   type `SQLLocalDB.exe start MSSQLLocalDB`
   It will tell you that this has now been started.
3. Go to Visual Studio and click View -> SQL Server Object Browser
   From here you will need to add a SQL Server (right click on SQL Server and 'Add  SQL Server'
4. In Server name: field enter '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB' - the Username/Servertype/Authentication should be left as default.
   Upon clicking Connect, the new database will show up with your new database

Databases are now stored in c:\users\[DATABASE-NAME] where as previously they were stored in your C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT

Hopefully this solves your issue with finding the SQLServer,
Cheers

Comment: A quick note: in the latest SSDT Preview for VS2015 there is now support for seeing & connecting to any LocalDB instances on your machine from the Connection Dialog used by SQL Server Object Explorer (Step 3). So you should no longer needto manually type in & verify the LocalDB server name. Might save you some of the manual work listed here. Download is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: Excellent Kevin, that is super handy for managing the LocalDbs. Cheers !

Comment: This works, thanks. Just to correct a typo in Step 2: `SQLLocalDB.exe start MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: I wondered why my DB appeared to be failing silently on creation!! Turns out EF's `Database.EnsureCreated()` was doing exactly what it was supposed to, just the db wasn't being listed is all. All the tutorials I looked at completely omitted this important detail, thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: This doesn't work if the database was created using a different Window's user.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered something different, I could see the `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` in the SQL Object Explorer in Visual Studio although I could not see it in the **SSMS**. So I followed @Maxithi and @JohnYoungTree response to start the LocalDB instance

To get the (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB working you:

1. Open CMD Prompt and type SQLLocalDB.exe info this shows all the
   current database servers on your local connection
2. You should see an option here for MSSQLLocalDB. type SQLLocalDB.exe
   start MSSQLLocalDB It will tell you that this has now been started.

After this, I went to SSMS and clicked on Connect, then I input Server Name as `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and I used my Windows Authentication. This worked awesomely!

Thank you @Maxithi and @JohnYoungTree

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was that someone didn't specify an Initial Catalog in the connection string.  Since database migrations were running to created the database, it was working; however, I could not find a database.  I finally found all the tables in the master database.  Afterwards, I corrected the connection string from:

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true
```

to

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//...for entity
public class ogrenciCONTEXT:DbContext
{
    public ogrenciCONTEXT():base("sqlim")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ogrenci> ogrenciler { get; set; }
}

// for WEB CONFIG 
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlim"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=dosyaismi; Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.